# Create Remote Solr core for solr cloud

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am very new to solr cloud and now integration solr cloud with external zookeeper.

I want to run 4 solr cores on 4 different server and manage by zookeeper.

So, I run solr cores on 4 different ip servers with different ports, 8983,8984,8985,8986 and bind with zookeeper. and it okay.

But when I create collection with following commend in one of core

```
​/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c articles -s 2 -rf 2
```

I got Error. because of remote server. but when I create 4 nodes in same ip with different port, it okay. Is there any command or any way to create 4 remote solr colres in solr cloud mode?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if cluster is configured correctly. Go to [localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS](http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS) and check if all 4 nodes are alive.

Then, have you tried to create the collection using the admin page?

Go to http://localhost:8983/solr and then go to Collections.

- Click Add Collection button
- name your collection, select a config name from the rop down list (you should have uploaded it in zookeeper first)
- insert 2 as num shards, go to advanced and then select 2 as max shard per node
- create the collection and see if it's ok selecting Cloud on menu.

Let me know if this works.